# in C can i do write(&'\n', 1) where write(char[], int)

Tags: c, coding-style

Can I do

```
write(&'\n', 1);
```

and is it equivalent to

```
char a = '\n';
write(&a, 1);
```

How would you solve this in a fashion way?

I'm tring to write the new-line caracter with a function that only take char array as first argument, and its dimension in second argument (dimension has to be specified because `\0` is a valid writable character)

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Solve what? No, you can't take an address of a character literal.

Comment: Wear a tight dress and saunter down the fashion runway? It's difficult to have any idea what you're asking.

Comment: edited to add a more usefull explanation

Comment: A character literal (For example `'a'` or `'\t'`) is evaluated to the ascii value of that caracter, so you can't use `&'a'` because it would be like writing `&95`

Comment: perhaps you want a string literal consisting of a single character? eg: `write("\n", 1);`, within C, string literals are constant pointers to char arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already pointed out, you cannot take the address of a character literal.

And even if you could, it would be the wrong type, because a character array usually must be zero-terminated.

What you are looking for is:

write("\n", 1);

Comment: it doesn't have to be zero terminated because i specify the lenght of the array, because \0 is a valid character to be write (i know, probabily the author of the write() should had use byte[] instead char[])

Comment: you are right, it should be uint8_t[] in pure c, but library code is Wiring

Comment: @lesto: That's why I wrote "usually": You didn't give details, and as a rule, I don't assume when using APIs. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can't take the address of a character literal, is because the compiler actually replaces it by the characters actual ASCII value, in this case 10. So your code actually is:

```
write(&10, 1);
```

And you can't take the address of a number literal, because it's most likely not stored in memory but part of the actual generated code.

Comment: ok, i understand your explanation and it seems the right answer. I was just tryng to "condensate" the code
`char a = '\n';
write(&a, 1);`
in only one line

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
write("\n", 1);
```

Comment: this seems a nice solution, but maybe compiler do some weird thing here? like change "\n" in '\n'...

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is for two different things:

`'\n'` is a character literal, and will be treated as an integer literal.

`char a` is a character variable.

you can get the address of a variable, not a literal.